# Modifying the date column calculation in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

[image]

I need to adjust the `time_in_weeks` column for the 34 number entry. When there is a duplicate `uniqueid` with a different `rma_created_date` that means there was some failure that occurred. The 34 needs to be changed to calculate the number of weeks between the new most recent `rma_created_date` (2020-10-15 in this case) and subtract the `rma_processed_date` of the above row 2020-06-28.

I hope that makes sense in terms of what I am trying to do.

So far I did this

```
def clean_df(df):
    '''
    This function will fix the time_in_weeks column to calculate the correct number of weeks
    when there is multiple failured for an item.
    '''
    
    # Sort by rma_created_date
    df = df.sort_values(by=['rma_created_date'])
```

Now I need to perform what I described above but I am a little confused on how to do this. Especially considering we could have multiple failures and not just 2.

I should get something like this returned as output

[image]

As you can see what happened to the `34` was it got changed to take the number of weeks between `2020-10-15` and `2020-06-26`

Here is another example with more rows

[image]

Using the expression suggested

```
df['time_in_weeks']=np.where(df.uniqueid.duplicated(keep='first'),df.rma_processed_date.dt.isocalendar().week.sub(df.rma_processed_date.dt.isocalendar().week.shift(1)),df.time_in_weeks)
```

I get this

Final note: if there is a date of 1/1/1900 then don't perform any calculation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question not very clear. Happy to correct if I interpreted it wrongly.

Try use `np.where(condition, choiceif condition, choice ifnotcondition)`

```
#Coerce dates into datetime
df['rma_processed_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['rma_processed_date'])
df['rma_created_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['rma_created_date'])

#Solution    

df['time_in_weeks']=np.where(df.uniqueid.duplicated(keep='first'),df.rma_created_date.sub(df.rma_processed_date),df.time_in_weeks)
```

Comment: I added an example of the output I should expect. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Where does 15 come from?

Comment: As you can see what happened to the 34 was it got changed to take the number of weeks between 2020-10-15 and 2020-06-26.

Comment: The 15 came from seeing that oh hey looks like I had another failure at 2020-10-15, okay, hmm, I need to adjust the 34 then and take the number of weeks between that new date 2020-10-15 and when we finished the first failure rate so the date above that row in the rma_processed_date column. Does that sense?

Comment: Could you please try `df['time_in_weeks']=np.where(df.uniqueid.duplicated(keep='first'),df.rma_processed_date.dt.isocalendar().week.sub(df.rma_processed_date.dt.isocalendar().week.shift(1)),df.time_in_weeks)`

Comment: That seems to work. Will it work for more than 2 records though?

Comment: I actually tried it one something else and it does not seem to work, I will update the post with the example.